# Loaf of French bread

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the English word describing a long thin loaf of French bread, which crust is appetisingly golden and crunchy, and the bread inside is light and fluffy?

Comment: I've read through some of your questions and answers, and they all are riveted on food. You say you are a foreign cook, which makes it understandable, but I still think that you should refer to the cooking section of StackExchange instead of EL&U

Comment: @Paola - Why have you used "through" rather than "across"?

Comment: @ Anglo Saxon. I used "read through" as per its definition of "to read something carefully from beginning to end in order to check details". I'm not aware of any usage of "read across".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly I think most Americans call it, "a loaf of French bread" or simply "a French bread".

Comment: Or baguette, at least in the Northeast US where there are large numbers of francophones.

Comment: I don't know that I'd go as far as *most*- certainly many do but baguette is not an uncommon word in America.  It is frequently seen on menus along with other loan words like *croissant*.  [Like here for example](http://boardnbrewdelmar.com/menu.html)- if surfers can understand it- it can't be too foreign.

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd find statistics on this. I expect an ngram search would find many more instances of "loaf" than "baguette", but most of those would be referring to bread in general. I wouldn't be surprised if this is a regionalism, but in New York, Ohio, and Michigan, where I've spent most of my life, I don't recall ever hearing someone use the word "baguette". I've heard it on television, that's about it.

Answer (score 24):

It's the same as it is in French: a ***[baguette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baguette)***

Answer (score 2):

In the UK we call it [a **stick** of French bread](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a%20stick%20of%20French%20bread%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (*baton* or *baguette* are a bit "middle-class")

Comment: so 'stick' is upper or lower class?

Comment: Eugh.  I detest people calling it a 'stick' of bread.  It's a 'baguette'.

Comment: @Jez,Mitch: I suspect most Brits wouldn't know the difference between a *baguette* and a *ficelle* (which I much prefer). I lived in France for a year, and I've nothing against the people or their language, but I do think it's slightly posh/affected to use their words when we've got perfectly good ones of our own. Though of course that's why we have *pork, beef,* and *mutton* - French words for what our Anglo-Saxon ancestors had to rear, slaughter, and cook for their posh Norman overlords!

Comment: You mean *bourgeois*? ^)^

Comment: @Robusto: Only a bit, but yeah. Around the time "English" really got going (Chaucer...Shakespeare), "courtly" language was French, and "churchly" was Latin. There's still a bit of a tendency to cast Anglo Saxon as the language of the peasantry (I f**king well hope OP reads this and recognises I'm rooting for his monicker as well as our shared tradition! ;)

Comment: no, in the UK we call it a baguette.

Comment: IME you are much more likely to hear 'French Stick' than 'stick of French bread', but baguette and baton are common. Lots of people *are* middle class and speak accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

It could also be [ficelle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficelle).

[image]

Comment: In the U.S., I think both *ficelles* and *baguettes* commonly get called *baguettes* (although you sometimes see *ficelles* that are called *ficelles*).

Comment: @PeterShor: There's a bakery a mile from me that sells both. The *ficelles* are thinner — mostly crust.

Comment: There's a bakery near where I grew up where you can buy a "grande baguette" (a baguette) or a "baguette" (a ficelle). But at least they get the French gender correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is described in English language dictionaries as a long thin loaf of white bread with French origins. It is usually pronounced as two syllables, with the tonic accent on the last syllable: Bag-ETT.
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/baguette
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/baguette

In France, some people will pronounce it as three syllables: bag-ET-te.

Comment: Hello Samuel. Welcome to English Language and Usage. The word Baguette was already suggested by @Jim above. Please try to read other answers when you post an answer to an old question. Good luck.